# PDF displaying garbage text in Internet explorer

Tags: javascript, java, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

I have a user who's trying to download a PDF file from Internet Explorer. When he clicks download the browser is displaying garbage data instead of downloading the file.
[See image below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Yhp0.png)
However the problem is not present on Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: Make sure your server serves the document with the correct MIME type.

Comment: That looks like encryption to me. Could you have possibly encrypted the pdf and not granted external users permissions? (assuming you wrote the website that supplies the pdf) also, it could be different pdf versions. I have had difficulty I'm the past with this.

Comment: The PDF is not encrypted.